# Таймер обратного отсчета javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Подскажите как обернуть в красный цвет каждую цифру в таймере? Спасибо

https://jsfiddle.net/s7p0yeam/7/

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  const newYear = new Date('Aug 22 2022 00:00:00');

  const daysVal = document.querySelector('.time-count__days .time-count__val');
  const hoursVal = document.querySelector('.time-count__hours .time-count__val');
  const minutesVal = document.querySelector('.time-count__minutes .time-count__val');

  function declOfNum(number, titles) {
let cases = [2, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2];
return titles[(number % 100 > 4 && number % 100 < 20) ? 2 : cases[(number % 10 < 5) ? number % 10 : 5]];
  }

  const timeCount = () => {
let now = new Date();
let leftUntil = newYear - now;

let days = Math.floor(leftUntil / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24);
let hours = Math.floor(leftUntil / 1000 / 60 / 60) % 24;
let minutes = Math.floor(leftUntil / 1000 / 60) % 60;

daysVal.textContent = days;
hoursVal.textContent = hours;
minutesVal.textContent = minutes;
  };

  timeCount();
  setInterval(timeCount, 1000);
});
```

```css
.time-count__content{
  display: flex;
}

.time-count__item{
  margin: 0px 60px 0px 0px;
}

.time-count__val{
  background: red;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="timer__time-count">
  <h2 class="time-count__title">До окончания акции осталось:</h2>
  <div class="time-count__content">
<div class="time-count__item time-count__days">
  <div class="time-count__val">00</div>
  <div class="time-count__text">дни</div>
</div>
<div class="time-count__item time-count__hours">
  <div class="time-count__val">00</div>
  <div class="time-count__text">часы</div>
</div>
<div class="time-count__item time-count__minutes">
  <div class="time-count__val">00</div>
  <div class="time-count__text">минуты</div>
</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Они и так в красном, не? Или подскажите подробнее как вы хотите.

Comment: что-бы каждая цифра была в красном, например 1 отдельно в красном, 5 отдельно  так каждую, сейчас цифры у дней, часов и минут вместе и оборачиваются в бэграунд тоже вместе, а надо что-бы раздельно

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Решение

Могу предложить такой вариант:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  const newYear = new Date('Aug 22 2022 00:00:00');

  const daysVal = document.querySelector('.time-count__days .time-count__val');
  const hoursVal = document.querySelector('.time-count__hours .time-count__val');
  const minutesVal = document.querySelector('.time-count__minutes .time-count__val');

  const timeCount = () => {
    let now = new Date();
    let leftUntil = newYear - now;

    let days = Math.floor(leftUntil / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24);
    let hours = Math.floor(leftUntil / 1000 / 60 / 60) % 24;
    let minutes = Math.floor(leftUntil / 1000 / 60) % 60;

    daysVal.innerHTML = days.toString().replace(/\d/gi, (substring) => `<span>${substring}</span>`);
    hoursVal.innerHTML = hours.toString().replace(/\d/gi, (substring) => `<span>${substring}</span>`);
    minutesVal.innerHTML = minutes.toString().replace(/\d/gi, (substring) => `<span>${substring}</span>`);
  };

  timeCount();
  setInterval(timeCount, 1000);
});
```

```css
.time-count__content {
  display: flex;
}

.time-count__item {
  margin: 0px 60px 0px 0px;
}

.time-count__val>* {
  background: red;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 40px;
  margin: 0 2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="timer__time-count">
  <h2 class="time-count__title">До окончания акции осталось:</h2>
  <div class="time-count__content">
    <div class="time-count__item time-count__days">
      <div class="time-count__val">00</div>
      <div class="time-count__text">дни</div>
    </div>
    <div class="time-count__item time-count__hours">
      <div class="time-count__val">00</div>
      <div class="time-count__text">часы</div>
    </div>
    <div class="time-count__item time-count__minutes">
      <div class="time-count__val">00</div>
      <div class="time-count__text">минуты</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```